# iOS Black Screen when pushing a UIViewController just in iOS 5.1

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, ios5.1

i searched a while for my problem and tried some hints, but I have still my issue.

Not sure when it occured the first time, but it still occurs.
I get a Black Screen, when i push a UIViewController to my UINavigationController.

I push the new ViewController in a TapGesture handler (code below).
The black screen appears just in iOS 5.1 in the simulator
and works fine in iOS 5.0 and 6.1.

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(id)recognizer
{
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [vc.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems: nil];

    int i = 0;
    CGPoint tapLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.scrollView];
    for(UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            // remove quickbars from suberview
            [self removeQuickBarFromSuperView:view];
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, tapLocation)) {
                vc.documentDir = self.documentDir;
                vc.imageSourcePath = self.imageSourcePath;
                vc.content = [content objectAtIndex:i] ;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

I also tested it with

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

(Or bundle: nil)

This as well works fine in 5.0 and 6.1 but cause the app to crash in 5.1.

I appreciate any advice.

kind regards

torben